# Image is not downloaded when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

```html
<a download="temp.jpg" href="https://codedecoder.pythonanywhere.com/media/embed/2021/10/07/temp.jpg">
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://codedecoder.pythonanywhere.com/media/embed/2021/10/07/temp.jpg">
</a>
```

When i click above element it takes to another site (a.href) rather than downloading the image

What should i add/remove ?

Comment: The `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs, you can not use it to trigger a download of resources from different origins.